# open a page / view in apache cordova

Tags: apache, jquery-mobile, mobile, cross-platform, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using apache cordova to create a application .

I have a little problem , I searched online and I can not understand why if you use the '  I change the page / view on the device .
It seems that not even take the touch input on the link .
Genymotion use of visual studio to perform the tests .
I also tried with the window.open javascript but I open a page in the browser coming out from the app

```
<a onclick='window.open('product.html', '_system');'>
or
<a href = 'product.html'>
```

can someone tell me how I can fix ?

Comment: I'm not sure why your "<a href=..." is not working, but, as written above, the window.open will not work.  You need to fix the quote marks like: 
`<a onclick="window.open('product.html', '_system');">`

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you will need to install the InAppBrowser Plugin for Cordova

```
http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

If you are using Visual Studio Tools for Cordova just double click on the config.xml > Plugins > Add InAppBrowser